# puppeteer open specific chrome profile

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

i tried use

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath:
      "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
    userDataDir: "C:/Users/Win10/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/",
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("chrome://version");
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
    });
  });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

but its not working its say

```
C:\Users\Win10\Downloads\Pupet\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\launch.js:267
                reject(new Error([
                       ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting

    at ChildProcess.onClose (C:\Users\Win10\Downloads\Pupet\node_modules\@puppeteer\browsers\lib\cjs\launch.js:267:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

Node.js v21.7.1
```

open specific chrome profile

Comment: Does "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" exist? Or is it the user data dir? Maybe try using plain Chromium to make sure the browser is not the problem and then make sure the data dir exists.

Comment: that code can open new tab but it keep not working, i try remove executablePath but not change anything

Comment: If it can open a new tab, then how is `Error: Failed to launch the browser process!` possible? This occurs when you're launching the browser, long before opening pages/tabs. Which line of code is failing, exactly?

Comment: idk either it stay blank

Comment: I'm suggesting that the error and behavior you're claiming is occurring is basically impossible. There is no way to get that error and also have a browser launch with a new tab, so something is missing or unclear here. Please clarify exactly which line is failing for you. This code works basically fine for me, so more details are necessary.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.